# Associate subdomain with PHP variable in the URL

Tags: php, url, subdomain

I manage a website with different country versions accessable by a php variable. Example for UK:

http://autocosts.org/index.php?c=UK

How do I associate the subdomain http://uk.autocosts.org to http://autocosts.org/index.php?c=UK

I'm using Hostgator severs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with URL Rewriting.

Put this in a .htaccess file in you website root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.autocosts\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://autocosts.org/index.php?c=%1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you kindly tell me what this option will do? Thank you

Comment: It will forward all calls on subdomains to the main domain index.php file. More on rewriting here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 2):

The domain is stored in the `HTTP_HOST` index of `$_SERVER`
You can try this

```
 $url = "http://autocosts.org/index.php?c=".
 $country =  substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0,2);
 $url .= strtoupper($country);
```

Comment: if you want to redirect the user to that url you can use `header("Location: ".$url);`

Comment: thank you, though this solution will create a paradox, for example this might be possible: de.autocosts.org/index.php?c=PT

Comment: that url is possible . but if the code is in index.php it will always s redirect to `http://autocosts.org/index.php?c=DE`

Answer (score -1):

You get get this effect by doing an internal redirect of the requests matching uk.autocosts.org.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uk.autocosts.org$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}?c=UK [PT]
```

However, you have to be careful with the GET URLs having a query string. You need special handling if you have GET URLs with query string.

Comment: Yes, that is what the question is about - read it carefully. It does exactly what is needed. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I quote the user. `I manage a website with different country versions accessable by a php variable. Example for UK`. So what he is trying to say is that he has different domains for the same website. So for example users from UK can access the website using `uk.autocosts.org`, people from india can access the website using `in.autocosts.org`and so on. So your solution would work only for the domain `uk.autocosts.org` and applying the same solution for other domains would prove unsuccessful.

Comment: Ok - I agree with you. Extending the solution to that is trivial. Now there is no point in repeating it since other answers have proposed that too already.